# Pandas DataFrame selection using text from another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

A quick disclosure: I come from R background and am switching to pandas (running on python 3.3.3).

I would like to select rows from a dataframe by using text from a dataframe entry. It's an elementry operation but I could not get around the syntax.

For example, with this DataFrame (sorry for the line split but I want to make the example clearer):

```
films = pandas.DataFrame({'$title':[  "The Godfather",
                                      "Pulp Fiction",
                                      "The Godfather: Part II",
                                      "Fight Club"],

                      '$director': [  "Coppola, Francis Ford",
                                      "Tarantino, Quentin",
                                      "Coppola, Francis Ford",
                                      "Fincher, David"]})
```

If I want to select all the films created by the first director, which would be "Coppola, Francis Ford", the command I am using is:

```
In [1]: director = films.iloc[[1]]["director"]

In [2]: director

        1    Coppola, Francis Ford
        Name: director, dtype: object

In [3]: a = films[ films["director"] == director ]

        ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

If I do this:

```
In [4]: a = films[ films["director"] == str(director) ]
```

I get an empty DataFrame. What's going on here? Seems like I'm missing something.

Comment: As kermit666 explained, there are quite errors in this question and using the dot notation made things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, first of all I see you made a couple of style/semantics mistakes which are common for R-to-Python converts:

- you don't need the `$` signs for your column names and it actually makes [column selection nicer](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access) as you can write `films.director` if the name is only `'director'` (it has to be a valid Python identifier for this syntactic sugar to work)
- indexing in Python starts at 0, not 1, so you select the 1st director as `films.director[0]`

Assuming you removed the `$` signs from your DataFrame definition, you can select the movies as:

```
In [16]: films[films['director'] == films['director'][0]]
Out[16]:
                director                   title
0  Coppola, Francis Ford           The Godfather
2  Coppola, Francis Ford  The Godfather: Part II
```

or even cleaner as `films[films.director == films.director[0]]`.

Using your original DataFrame you can perform your query with:

```
director = films.iloc[[1]]['$director'][1]
films[films['$director'] == director]
```

One error was that you first defined the table with `'$director'` and then queried it with `'director'` as the column name.

The `[1]` in the end is necessary because you indexed the DataFrame with a list `[1]`, instead of a value `1`, so you got back a Series, as CT Zhu already noticed. [List indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) is meant more for selecting several arbitrary elements such as `films.iloc[[1, 3]]`. In your case it would be clearer to write

```
director = films.iloc[1]['$director']
```

Also, note that this still gets Tarantino and not Coppola.

Answer (score 1):

I think `films[ films["director"] == films.ix[0, 'director' ]]` will suffice.

The reason `films.iloc[[1]]["director"]` won't work is because it is a `Series`, not a `string`.

If you want to use `iloc`, do: `films.iloc[1]["director"]` instead of `films.iloc[[1]]["director"]`

Also:

```
In [241]:

str(films.iloc[[1]]["director"])
Out[241]:
'1    Tarantino, Quentin\nName: director, dtype: object'
```

so, `films[ films["director"] == str(director) ]` won't match anything and will return a empty dataframe.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look into the answer when I get back. I believe when iloc[1] won't give me the first element if I sort the dataframe.

Comment: Also, notice that index in `python` starts at 0, instead of 1 in `R` and `matlab`, cheers!